# JQuery slider with attribute for what to control, reusable prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-slider

In my project i intend to have multiple similar sliders therefore it would be interesting to make them using a prototype:

To set what the sliders control I want to use a "motorLabel". I have tried adding an attribute to the slider below but it does not find the attribute.
Can you please help me change the code to a usable slider prototype.

```
$(function() {
    $('#svgbasics').svg({onLoad: drawOpenSwitch});
    //Slider for Last:
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
        motorLabel: 'm1',
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: "min",
        min: 1,
        max: 200,
        value: 50,
        change: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );

            console.log(this.motorLabel); // RETURNS UNDEFINED
            eval(this.motorLabel.motorSetLast(ui.value));

        }
    }).draggable();
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass argument on html instead :

```
<div id="slider" data-motor-label="m1"></div>
```

And in your change function :

```
$(this).data('motor-label');
```

To get the value.

Comment: Works: eval(m1.motorSetLast(ui.value));
Returns m1: console.log($(this).data('motor-label'));
Says no method found: eval($(this).data('motor-label').motorSetLast(ui.value));

Comment: By the way, what's `m1` ?

Comment: m1 = Object.create(motor);
m1.motorLabel= 'm1';

Comment: Works: eval($(this).data('motor-label')+'.motorSetLast(ui.value)');  
Notice the citation on the method call making it a string as well...